# Calling a preprocessor tool from Java

Tags: java, preprocessor

I have a C source that I have preprocessed using MCPP, a preprocessor. I want to parse this preprocessed source with Java parser. For that I need to call it from Java. Is there some API available to handle such call. I plan to execute DOS commands as a batch file and execute it at Java Runtime.
When I used the standard exec method

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();  
Process dos = r.exec("cmd.exe /c C:\\mcpp\\bin\\mcpp.exe -Iinclude csample.c");
```

It gives error that preprocessor cannot open input file.
Suggestions awaited.

**cmd parameters edited**

Comment: Please edit the code in your post to show the actual "dos commands" parameter(s).  That's where the problem is.  When posting code be careful about editing out "non-significant" information.

Answer (score 0):

[ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) comes to my mind

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();  
Process dos = r.exec("C:\\mcpp\\bin\\mcpp.exe -Iinclude csample.c");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your command is being run in a different directory than you expect.  You need to provide the appropriate directory using the three-argument version of [`exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29):

```
public Process exec(String command,
                    String[] envp,
                    File dir)
             throws IOException
```

where the third argument gives the current directory for the command being executed.  Make sure to set it to the directory where the input is located.

EDIT: Example:

```
r.exec("cmd.exe /c C:\\mcpp\\bin\\mcpp.exe -Iinclude csample.c", 
       null, // inherit current process environment
       new File("/path/containing/csample.c"));
```

Comment: could you be more specific with an example, I don't understand the syntax for exec command that you wrote.